# Copy only cell content in OOCalc

Tags: openoffice, spreadsheet, openoffice-calc

In OOCalc, when I copy a cell with ctrl-c ctrl-v, it copies everything, also the style, from source to destination.

However, I want to copy only the content, leaving the formatting of the destination cell intact.

Anyone knows hot to do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I've discovered how to do it reading the answer of a related question:

1. Hit ctrl-c on the source cell
2. Select the destination cell
3. Right clic -> Paste special
4. Untick "Past all" and then "Formats"

That's all!